# plugins to make like button for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

I've been looking for like and unlike button plugin for ROR. Is there any reference for me??

user can like specific post and can unlike back, and there is a count of total user likes the post

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/jaggederest/acts_as_voteable)

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base    
  acts_as_voteable  
end
```

And then rather than have a 1-5 scale, just have a -1 or 1. That could be your unlike/like.

Comment: hey Jesse... u save my day!! thanks ya

Answer (score 0):

i think that what you trying do can be implemented easily with a column in your database something like "like" and "unlike", and when the button is clicked you incremment "like" or "onlike"....

Comment: the only problem with this method is you won't remember which posts a certain user liked, or vice versa which users liked a certain post. I would store a separate table with a user_id and a post_id, and then store the increment you're talking about as a performance enhancement if necessary.